# Do guitar endpins get damaged?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

My guitar is already more than 5 years old. It has an endpin which I have never actually used. I bought audio jack and connected it to pc via microphone output. Sound is so unstable that I gave up on this idea quickly. So I was wondering, what is causing this problem, cables, pc output or guitar endpin. If I buy guitar combo is it possible that there still will be a problem with sound? Or most likely directly connecting it to combo will fix the problem.

Comment: Can you add some more details on what you mean by 'unstable'?

Comment: Simply saying sound is unclear, distant and lagging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like the most efficient way to find the defective component is to figure out a process of elimination by substituting out each component starting with your connecting cable, then try plugging into an amp. If it works fine there then suspect the interface or computer. If it still doesn't work right then suspect the guitar and its parts, depending on your skill level, you may choose to continue the process of elimination by attempting to bypass each component in your guitar, or you may choose to take it in and have a repairman fix it for you.

Comment: I have 2 cables, one with noth sides thicc jack, and other to guitar jack to computer jack, i also have small output changers or whatever its called. I tried what you said with my pc. It had no sound, but when i tried with laptop it had some sound but the sound was very distant and unclear. So this really got me confused

Comment: @Saba- If you plug your guitar into an amp and it works ok, then you'll know that the problem exists in either the interface or the computer, but first you need to determine that in fact the pickup and components in the guitar are functioning properly. Then you'll need to determine if the signal from the guitar is high level enough to drive the input of the interface, which possibly requires a line level signal to drive it to full output. Guitar level signals are usually much lower level signals. A preamp can boost this signal for you if you need it.